# Unable to capture the exit code of `/bin/sh`

Tags: bash, shell, docker, sh, busybox

I am using `/bin/bash` as the outermost shell, and I'm using the default `/bin/sh` from `busybox`.

Below, I am able to capture the exit code as I would expect:

```
$ docker run -it --rm busybox /bin/sh -c "bin/sh -c \"cat /foo/bar\" && echo Shell Result: $?" || echo Docker Result: $?
cat: can't open '/foo/bar': No such file or directory
Docker Result: 1
```

Clearly `cat /foo/bar` has failed, which is how we enter the statement on the other side of `||`. However, when I attempted to echo the result the value of `$?` is `0` (shown below):

```
$ docker run -it --rm busybox /bin/sh -c "bin/sh -c \"cat /foo/bar\" || echo Shell Result: $?" || echo Docker Result: $?
cat: can't open '/foo/bar': No such file or directory
Shell Result: 0
```

Where is the result stored, or how can I capture it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Variables get expanded in double quotes. That applies to `$?` as well.

```
$ true; /bin/sh -c "cat /foo/bar || echo Result: $?"
cat: /foo/bar: No such file or directory
Result: 0
$ false; /bin/sh -c "cat /foo/bar || echo Result: $?"
cat: /foo/bar: No such file or directory
Result: 1
```

Solution: use single quotes or escape the `$`:

```
$ true; /bin/sh -c 'cat /foo/bar || echo Result: $?'
cat: /foo/bar: No such file or directory
Result: 1
$ true; /bin/sh -c "cat /foo/bar || echo Result: \$?"
cat: /foo/bar: No such file or directory
Result: 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You're seeing this because variable expansion is being done on the command before it is executed. Try escaping the $?:

```
docker run -it --rm busybox /bin/sh -c "bin/sh -c \"cat /foo/bar\" || echo Shell Result: \$?" || echo Docker Result: $?
```

Alternatively, if you don't need any other variable expansion in your command, just use single quotes (then you also don't need to escape the inner quotes):

```
docker run -it --rm busybox /bin/sh -c 'bin/sh -c "cat /foo/bar" || echo Shell Result: $?' || echo Docker Result: $?
```